# Set focus on element with Protractor

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, automated-tests, focus

I'm interacting with a web page using Protractor. I need to browse a dropdown list (which shows 1/3 of a bigger list) and I'm using the DOWN key in order to do it:

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.DOWN).perform();
```

When I hit the bottom of the list, I click on a button to go to part 2/3 of the entire list.

The problem is, after hitting this button and accessing part 2/3, I'm not able to browse the list. The focus is on the button I just clicked. The browse the list, the focus needs to be on one of the list's elements.

How can I set the focus on a web element using Protractor?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the keys directly at an element with protractor WebElement

```
element.sendKeys(protractor.Key.DOWN)
```

I would suspect you would send the keys to the dropdown list container.

Here is a helpful resource

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.sendKeys